# How to export to gltf with z up?

Tags: modeling, export, gltf

I have the following model:

[image]

In this configuration the model is positioned so that z is up. I want this, z up is the convention I use everywhere.

I try to export to gltf disabling the y up option:

[image]

But when i re-import the mdoel it seems as if -y is up:

[image]

How can I export the model such that z is up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, the glTF specification defines +Y as "up" for the format. This was done (along with meter scale and +Z front) with the goal that assets from different sources would be compatible together in a scene.  This is why the Blender importer presumes +Y up.

It's expected that glTF will auto-convert to any native system, for example convert glTF's +Y up to Blender's +Z up automatically during import.  It may actually be inappropriate for the exporter to offer any option here to do anything other than automatically convert Blender's +Z up to glTF's +Y up on the way out, but removing an existing export option is always contentious, so it hasn't happened yet.

For reference:  https://registry.khronos.org/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html#coordinate-system-and-units

[image: coordinate system screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think the way it works is GlTf always expects +Y Up when importing, and the +Y Up export option actually acts as a converter to +Y Up coordinates.

Comment: So there is no way to instruct blender to use z up when importing?

Comment: What I mean is, export with +Y Up enabled, and it will then import as +Z Up correctly